# How to add numbers in a string in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I would like to make a Text Label say this;

"THE TROLLGE WILL BEGIN IN (seconds left) SECONDS"

but I do not know how. Any help to solve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```lua
local secondsLeft = 5 --5 seconds left example
local stringResult = "THE TROLLGE WILL BEGIN IN "..tostring(secondsLeft).." SECONDS"
```

Convert number to string then concat it into your target string

Comment: Do I still have to make the seconds left a variable though?

Comment: replace secondsLeft variable at stringResult with your variable that store seconds left

Comment: the `local secondsLeft = 5` is just an example of a variable that store seconds left

Answer (score 0):

Oldschool with `string.format()`...

```
local secondsLeft = 5 --5 seconds left example
local stringResult = string.format("%s %d %s","THE TROLLGE WILL BEGIN IN", secondsLeft, "SECONDS")
```